# angularJS: how to revert / prevent radio button event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a (non-working) example in http://jsfiddle.net/S2kc7/1/

```
<radio ng-model="value" ng-value="foo">
<radio ng-model="value" ng-value="bar">
```

if a user does NOT approve, i'd like to revert to the previous state.

e.g., if ng-model="value" was on "foo" before the user clicked on "bar", and then the user chose to cancel, i'd like to prevent that event, and remain on "value=foo", without anything getting changed or $watched.

I tried:

```
$scope.$watch('value', function(){ newvalue = oldvalue })
$scope.clicked = function($event) { $event.preventDefault(); }
<radio ng-change="check_and_prevent()">
```

none of these methods were able to cancel the event (in my humle tests). some of the remains of the tests are commented out in the jsfiddle above.

can i prevent event on <radio>?

can i prevent event on <select> ?

**EDIT**
@jose's answer worked for the case presented, but not in the real website;

In my website, "value" is actually a property of an object; but even that works out in jsFiddle's sterile environment:  http://jsfiddle.net/L5555/

but not in my website.

I can't tell what's the difference, and i can't reveal my website.

thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it work by using ng-change.  Make sure that each radio has the ng-change on it

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="foo" ng-change="validateChange()">
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="bar" ng-change="validateChange()">
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="zaz" ng-change="validateChange()">
```

And  you can use this logic in your controller

```
$scope.value= $scope.preval= 'foo';
$scope.validateChange = function() {
    if(confirm('revert???  value='+$scope.value+'  preval='+$scope.preval)) {
        $scope.preval = $scope.value;
    } else {
        $scope.value = $scope.preval;
    }
};
```

Updated and working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/S2kc7/3/

Comment: There must be something else on the page then that is modifying the variable.  It might be some other directive or maybe even something in your controller that is making it change.  Is that value being watched/used/modified by any other directives?

Comment: thank you; the page's logic changed since i asked it, so i can't see the problem anymore. anyway your solution worked.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer does not covers scenerios which makes ajax calls on model change.

You can completely prevent changes by surrounding radio inputs with label tag.

```
<label ng-click="confirmChange($event)"><input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="foo" ></label>



$scope.confirmChange = function(event) {
   if(!confirm('sure?')) {
     event.preventDefault();
   } 
};
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my bacon!

Comment: Actually if you click on the radio 'cyrcle' directly instead of clicking on the label it won't work

Comment: Maybe sending same method to ng-change event of input element would do it.